# Lambda expression problem

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, lambda

I'm new with lambda expressions and linq and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

```
GroupSet groupToChange = context.GroupSet.Select(q => q.groupId == groupId);
```

I'm trying to get and change the name of an entity.

```
groupToChange.groupName = newGroupName;
```

I'm not having any problems with the second line though. Any ideas? It tells me I can't convert bool to GroupSet but the function returns what it finds, right?

Comment: It's Lambda Expression not lamda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `Where` instead of `Select`.

`Where` returns everything that matches the supplied lambda expression.
`Select` is a transformation. It transforms each element using the supplied lambda expression.

Additionally, `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, because it can't know that only one element will match your condition. If *you* know it will only return one result, append `Single` to the query, to return only one element. Only then it will compile:

```
GroupSet groupToChange = context.GroupSet.Where(q => q.groupId == groupId)
                                         .Single();
```

If you are unsure, whether or not one element will match, use `SingleOrDefault`:

```
GroupSet groupToChange = context.GroupSet.Where(q => q.groupId == groupId)
                                         .SingleOrDefault();
```

The difference between those two:
`Single` will throw an exception, if the result set of `Where` is empty.
`SingleOrDefault` will return `default(T)`, i.e. `null` in your case.

Comment: A better answer should also mention `Single` et al.

Comment: I'm still getting a cast error; Error 6 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Gruppkoll.GroupSet>' to 'Gruppkoll.GroupSet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) It's so strange, it should automatically extract the entity right?

Comment: Thanks for being so fast though

Comment: @Phil: It should work with using either Single or SingleOrDefault

Answer (score 3):

```
GroupSet groupToChange = context.GroupSet.Where(q => q.groupId == groupId);
```

Since you want the list filtered by the condition, use Where instead of Select.

groupToChange will be a collection, so you should assign the newGroupName to individual elements in the collection, if it has only one element you could do the following

```
groupToChange.Single().groupName = newGroupName;
```

otherwise you have to iterate through each element and assign them

```
foreach(var g in groupToChange)
    g.groupName = newGroupName;
```

Also look at SingleOrDefault, First, FirstOrDefault methods

Answer (score 2):

The `Select` is a transformation as has been pointed out, so when you say:

```
.Select(q => q.groupId == groupId)
```

what you get is a list of booleans based on if the element in the GroupSet has a groupId equal to the given `groupId`

it sort of like doing:

```
List<bool> results = new List<bool>; 
foreach(group in GroupSet)
{
    results.Add(group.goupId==groupId);
}
return results;
```

What you want is either

- `Where` which will filter based on the lambda expression and return all instances that match the filter.
- `First` which will return the first element that matches the lambda expression(and throw an exception if none do)
- `FirstOrDefault` which will return the first element which matches or the default (probably null in this case) if none match.
- `Single` will return the only element that matches and throw an exception if there is not exactly one
- `SingleOrDefault` will return the only element that matches or the default (probably null) if none matches but throw an exception if there is more than one.

Exactly which to choose depends on such factors as, will the list always contain an element which matches?  Is it an error condition if not? will there be more than 1? Is more than 1 an error condition.  Obviously if you know there will only ever be one then `First` will be quicker as it will stop when it hits the first one, but `Single` will iterate until it checks the whole list or finds a second element.

Answer (score 1):

`Select` returns `IEnumerable<TResult>` and you want to return only one element - as Jon mentioned you should use `Single`